# Create a folder inside another with parents argument in java desktop application

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to create a folder inside another folder by setting the id of parents property, but the folder is not created inside it.I need a solution for a java desktop application but i cant found the right syntax for the parents property in order to perform my post request correctly (HttpPost object is the org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost)

```
HttpPost post2 = new HttpPost("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files");
post2.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
post2.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer XXXXXX");

JsonObject jsonObject2 = new JsonObject();
jsonObject2.addProperty("title", userid);
jsonObject2.addProperty("parents", "['kind': 'drive#parentReference', 
{'id':    '"+MY_PARENT_FILE_ID+"'}]");
jsonObject2.addProperty("mimeType", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

post2.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject2.toString()));
HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(post2);
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or suggest a solution?

Comment: Double check how many quotes you have around the parent id

Answer (score 1):

I use the Google API Ruby Client gem found at https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client.

```
authenticated_client_and_drive
```

is a method that returns and authenticated client and drive instance. Essentially, you make a post request to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token with a token that looks like:

```
{'refresh_token' => USERS_EXISTING_REFRESH_TOKEN,
'client_id' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
'client_secret' => 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET',
'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'}
```

Then it's as simple as implementing a method like:

```
def create_folder_within_folder(title, parent_folder_id)

    # INPUTS: a folder title (string) and parent_folder_id (string) 
    # OUTPUT: the file_id (string) of the newly created folder

    @client, @drive = authenticated_client_and_drive

    @folder = @drive.files.insert.request_schema.new({
        'title' => title,
        'description' => 'Your Description Here',
        'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents' => [{"id" => parent_folder_id}]
    })

    @result = @client.execute(
      :api_method => @drive.files.insert,
      :body_object => @folder)

    return @result.data.id

end
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: thank you very lot for your answer, but i need a solution for a java desktop application and this approach is not applicable in my case. More specifically i have to found the right syntax for parents property in order to perform my post request (HttpPost is the org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost).